# Extract (International) Mobile Phones from database

Tags: phone-number

Is there an easy way of extracting international mobile phones from a database? 
Has anybody in their midnight surfing come accross open source software or resources that address this?

Any pointers are welcome, thanks!

Updates:

*1: I have a database with phone numbers and wanted to iterate through all phone numbers and only extract or save international mobile (cell) phones. Any open source software or scripts or int. mobile lists for achieving this?

*2: Found a few lists that could be merged to use in script for validating mobile phones.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_mobile_phone_codes
- http://pastebin.com/ziYj1uy4

*3: Google's common Java, C++ and Javascript library for parsing, formatting, storing and validating international phone numbers: http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comment: yeah, sure. Sorry for being so vague! I have updated question *1

Answer (score 5):

If Suppose you are from India so all the mobile numbers other than +91 country code will be international for you so I have taken Liberty of writing this query for you

```
select * from table_name where mobile_number not in (select mobile_number from table_name where mobile_number like '+91%')
```

This will give you data from your table other than those who are local numbers

Let me know if it was useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was looking more for an out of the box solution or open source project that goes someway to address international mobile phone recognition/validation, and your answer could be part of the solution. Maybe something like: http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/